# Add [[j]] or other info used in each line inside a loop in R

Tags: r, loops, web-scraping

My doubt is how to include a column in "`my_data`" (`my_data$sector`), showing what `url_list[[j]]` or `url_info` was used for that line. 
Each url will bring me a table (35 x 100) and I need to show what element was the source when putting all together.

```
url_list <- vector()
url_info <- vector()

# then, i feed it. 
total_pages <- 1:5   #for my use, i need almost 100 pages

for (i in total_pages) {
    url_list [i] <- paste('http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=',i,sep = "")
    url_info [i] <- paste('sector_',i,sep = "")
}

url_list
>> [1] "http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=1" "http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=2"
[3] "http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=3" "http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=4"
[5] "http://www.mylink/result.php?sector=5"

url_info
>> [1] "sector_1" "sector_2" "sector_3" "sector_4" "sector_5"

#scraping
my_data <- list()

for (j in seq_along(url_list)) {
    my_data[[j]] <- url_list[[j]] %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_node("table") %>%
        html_table()
}


final_data <- cbind(do.call(rbind, my_data))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a list of url with tables you can rbind, but try something below, it will append the url to the last column.

You have to try it on your actual data for rbind:

```
my_data <- list()
url_list=c(
"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_population",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_and_territories_by_historical_population",
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_and_dependencies_by_population")

for (j in seq_along(url_list)) {
    my_data[[j]] <- url_list[[j]] %>% 
        read_html() %>% 
        html_node("table") %>%
        html_table() %>%
        mutate(url=url_list[j])
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
pipe_function <- . %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_node("table") %>%
  html_table()

tibble(url_info,url_list) %>% 
  mutate(table = url_list %>% map_dfr(pipe_function))
```

Comment: Error in . %>% read_html() %>% html_node("table") %>% html_table() : 
  can't find the function "%>%"

Comment: Did you load the tidyverse?

Comment: Yes, that line worked well. But it's returning another error: ```Erro: 'sector_1' does not exist in current working directory ('c:/program files/rstudio/bin').```

Comment: I can't help you with that